# Saving ID for specific onclick element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a JavaScript where you write a message and the time and message appears on the website. The function doing this is "renderMessage". However, it includes an image you can click to delete that message and then I want to write all the remaining ones again. Problem is that I don't know how to save some sort of ID so I know which image was clicked so I delete the correct position in the array of messages.

The code for renderMessage is:

```
function renderMessage(theMessage, theMessages){
    var text = document.createTextNode(theMessage.getText());
    var time = document.createTextNode(theMessage.getDate());
    var div = document.getElementById("writeMessages");

    div.appendChild(text);
    div.appendChild(time);

    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = 'img/deletePic.png';

    div.appendChild(image);
    div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

    image.onclick = function(e){

        theMessages.splice(); // This is where I don't know how to remove the correct one
        removeAll(theMessages); // This removes all html code in the div and writes 
                                // the array again (hopefully this time with the correct
                                // element removed from it)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thumbs up for using plain js.

I would say you enclose the message, time and the image into another element. My be a `ul` `li` block. And, when you render the messages in `DOM`, you set the message id as `id` attribute of the `li` so it will be something like this

```
<ul>
    <li>Message 1 - 10:21 PM <img src="remove jpg"/></li>
    <li>Message 2 - 10:22 PM <img src="remove jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

and your js code can be,

```
image.onclick = function () {
    var message_id = this.parentNode.id;

    // here you got the message id.
    // splice your message array and render
}
```

Why are you re-rendering all the messages? You could simply

```
    // splice your message array and render

    var li = this.parentNode;
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Please excuse my very beginner-level knowledge but I don't quite understand how I would implement that solution. Do I need to make the ul in the html code? Because I'm trying to do the entire thing through js. Is there a way to do the list through js?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using js. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AG95u/1/). (Edited the fiddle).
Make a ul just like you made a div, and append children to that ul.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing wrong or what, but "var message_id = this.parentNode.id;" seems to always just delete the first element in the array for me when I use "theMessages.splice(message_id, 1);" so I guess I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: post the complete loop for rendering in a fiddle, may be you are not correctly setting the `id`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Lb/

Maybe a lot of code to just look through, the only thing not in there is the message class and the init function (that gets the message)

Comment: Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Lb/2/, its not the best way to it, but you can get it working, then try to optimize.

Comment: Ah, message writing works great :) But if I write say 3 messages, then I remove 1 and try to write a new I get an Uncaught TypeError and cannot call method 'getText' of undefined. Is it the "TimesWritten" variable that is wrongly calculated?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant when I said its not the best way to do it. Could you try the update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Lb/3/). Instead of removing all and re-rendering, It will only remove the specific child from the DOM.

Comment: I actually got it to work now :) Thank you so much for your help, you've been amazing!

Answer (score 0):

you can save the id of the message inside an attribute of the element. eg `<div class="your_message_container data-id="14">...</div>`

Using jquery for example you can read that attribute with `$(your_selector).attr("data-id");` and write it with `$(your_selector).attr("data-id", "new_value");`

As an alternative, also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Edit:

i made you a fiddle with pure js: http://jsfiddle.net/A64zh/2/ Note that the id of the message element must equal the data-message-id attribute of your delete image.

the advantage of using an element attribute for storing the id is that your javascript does not depend on the html structure like it does if you are using something like `this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild....` which would need to be changed if you would add more html layers in between the two

Comment: Hmm, could you explain the div class thing further? Or give a link to more information? Also, it is a course in JavaScript and we are not supposed to use jquery at the moment, I prefer a purely JavaScript-based solution